# List valid color schemes?

Tags: colorscheme

I just found out about the `:colorscheme` command. Is there a way that I can get a list of valid color schemes from Vim? I'd like to be able to do this from within Vim, not from a list somewhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`:help c_Ctrl-d`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-D) after `:colorscheme`.

So, `:colorscheme`<kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> will output the colorschemes you have available to you.

Make sure there is a space after `:colorscheme`

Comment: worked on windows too!

Answer (score 10):

Another way to show the list is by `set wildmenu`. With this, after `:colorscheme` + `space` + `tab`, a list of completion is displayed and also selectable with arrow key or `Ctrl-N` and `Ctrl-P`. This is not only work on colorscheme, but also on other cmdline completion. The behavior is affected by `wildmode` and better set to the default value `full`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this in Vimscript, you can get a [List](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#List) of color schemes by using the getcompletion() function:

```
let c = getcompletion('', 'color')
echo c
```

This is a bit simpler than the existing Vimscript answer, which scans the filesystem.

See `:help getcompletion()` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers show the interactive way of showing what colorschemes are
available, but no one has mentioned a way of getting a list that can be used in
vimscript.  This is an adaptation of my answer for [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/list-known-filetypes).

This solution uses the `'runtimepath'` option to get all available colorscheme
directories, and then fetches a list of the vimscript files in those directories
with their extensions removed.  This may not be the safest way to do it, so
improvements are welcome:

```
function! GetColorschemes()
    " Get a list of all the runtime directories by taking the value of that
    " option and splitting it using a comma as the separator.
    let rtps = split(&runtimepath, ",")
    " This will be the list of colorschemes that the function returns
    let colorschemes = []

    " Loop through each individual item in the list of runtime paths
    for rtp in rtps
        let colors_dir = rtp . "/colors"
        " Check to see if there is a colorscheme directory in this runtimepath.
        if (isdirectory(colors_dir))
            " Loop through each vimscript file in the colorscheme directory
            for color_scheme in split(glob(colors_dir . "/*.vim"), "\n")
                " Add this file to the colorscheme list with its everything
                " except its name removed.
                call add(colorschemes, fnamemodify(color_scheme, ":t:r"))
            endfor
        endif
    endfor

    " This removes any duplicates and returns the resulting list.
    return uniq(sort(colorschemes))
endfunction
```

You can then use thie list returned by this function in vimscript.  For
instance, you could simply echo each colorscheme:

```
for c in GetColorschemes() | echo c | endfor
```

I won't explain what each individual function or command does here, but here is
a list of the help pages for all of the ones I used:

- `:help 'runtimepath'`
- `:help :let`
- `:help :let-&`
- `:help split()`
- `:help :for`
- `:help expr-.`
- `:help :if`
- `:help isdirectory()`
- `:help glob()`
- `:help fnamemodify()`
- `:help add()`
- `:help uniq()`
- `:help sort()`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

`:colorscheme`, Then hit the <kbd>space</kbd> key and then the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

Comment: Note that is it depends in your `wildmenu` and `wildchar` settings and that this answer is basically the same as [tivn's one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3005/1841)