# List known filetypes

Tags: syntax-highlighting

How can I get a list of the names of filetypes that vim currently knows about?

I want to be able to do this so that when vim doesn't automatically detect a filetype I can try some of the filetypes vim knows about that may be similar and see if they provide reasonable syntax highlighting.

I know that vimscript files dealing with filetypes are put in the `ftplugin` directory by convention but they don't need to be (I'm not sure, but I don't think the vimscript files in the `ftplugin` directory are special) so I want to just ask vim what filetypes it knows about, regardless of how it learned about them.

Comment: You can view a list when you try to autocomplete on `:setfiletype ` (i.e. with `Tab` after a space). Not sure if it's the complete list, or how to capture it to some buffer/file.

Comment: Use `<c-d>` instead of `<tab>` to list completions.

Comment: Type a letter or a few to filter the list and show entries which is started with these letters.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Simple Solution**

Type `:setfiletype` *(with a space afterwards)*, then press `Ctrl-d`.

See `:help cmdline-completion` for more on autocompletion in vim's command line.

**Complicated Solution**

This solution uses the `'runtimepath'` option to get all available syntax directories, and then fetches a list of the vimscript files in those directories with their extensions removed.  This may not be the safest way to do it, so improvements are welcome:

```
function! GetFiletypes()
    " Get a list of all the runtime directories by taking the value of that
    " option and splitting it using a comma as the separator.
    let rtps = split(&runtimepath, ",")
    " This will be the list of filetypes that the function returns
    let filetypes = []

    " Loop through each individual item in the list of runtime paths
    for rtp in rtps
        let syntax_dir = rtp . "/syntax"
        " Check to see if there is a syntax directory in this runtimepath.
        if (isdirectory(syntax_dir))
            " Loop through each vimscript file in the syntax directory
            for syntax_file in split(glob(syntax_dir . "/*.vim"), "\n")
                " Add this file to the filetypes list with its everything
                " except its name removed.
                call add(filetypes, fnamemodify(syntax_file, ":t:r"))
            endfor
        endif
    endfor

    " This removes any duplicates and returns the resulting list.
    " NOTE: This might not be the best way to do this, suggestions are welcome.
    return uniq(sort(filetypes))
endfunction
```

You can then use this function in whatever way you want, such as printing all of the values in the list.  You could accomplish that like so:

```
for f in GetFiletypes() | echo f | endfor
```

Note that this probably can be compacted quite a bit, it is just like this for readability.  I won't explain every function and command used here, but here are all the help pages for them:

- `:help 'runtimepath'`
- `:help :let`
- `:help :let-&`
- `:help split()`
- `:help :for`
- `:help expr-.`
- `:help :if`
- `:help isdirectory()`
- `:help glob()`
- `:help fnamemodify()`
- `:help add()`
- `:help uniq()`
- `:help sort()`

Comment: When I type `set filetype<space><c d>`, it shows me a list, but html is not in the list.  Java is not in the list.  How do I show filetype names in the sense of filetypes that correspond to the syntax formatting configurations?

Comment: @JohnMeyer: I made the same mistake. The command is actually `:setfiletype` without the typical space between "set" and "filetype". You can find more info with `:help :setfiletype` and `:help ftdetect`.

Comment: I've tried this, and it works! btw, I can use `:setfiletype ht<Ctrl+D>` to list filetype starting with ht, which filters unwanted results. :)

Comment: Even pre-`completion()` the double loop is a bit complex as we have `globpath(&rtp, 'syntax/**/*.vim')`. With the new object syntax the same code becomes: `echo globpath(&rtp, 'syntax/**/*.vim', 0, 1)->map({ _, v -> v->fnamemodify(':t:r')})->sort()->uniq()`. But then the `ftplugin` directory also needs to be analysed, and the specific `{filetype}_whatever.vim` pattern needs to be taken into acount as well.

Answer (score 31):

If your version of vim is recent enough (v7.4.2011+), you can ask for known filetypes with the function we can now use to help define manual autocompletion: [`getcompletion()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcompletion%28%29)

```
:echo getcompletion('', 'filetype')
```

If you want to restrict the list to filetypes starting with a `'c'`, you'd call

```
:echo getcompletion('c', 'filetype')
```

and so on.

Note: unlike solutions that parse the file names and directory names in `$VIMRUNTIME/{syntax,ftplugin}/`, this solution analyses `'runtimepath'` as well.
As far as I understand, it doesn't see new filetypes defined/registered on the fly with `set ft=foobar`, nor after autocommands.

Answer (score 4):

You can also print all file types in the terminal by running the following 2 commands:

1.

```
cd $(vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' | tr -d '\015')
```

2.

```
cat <(ls -1 ftplugin/*.vim) <(ls -1 syntax/*.vim) | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 basename | sort | uniq | cut -f 1 -d '.'
```

First command simply navigates to your vim runtime path (for me it was */usr/share/vim/vim80*).

Second command lists all the file type names in the two folders where vim stores the file type definitions.

### Update

Suggested improvements to the two commands by muru which offer:

```
cd "$(vim -Nesc '!echo $VIMRUNTIME' -c qa)"
find syntax ftplugin -iname '*.vim' -exec basename -s .vim {} + | sort -u
```

Comment: That is waaaay too complicated a pipeline. Using `tr` to convert newlines to null only to convert it back the very next command, process substitution when simple command grouping would do. I'd suggest something like: `find syntax ftplugin -iname '*.vim' -exec basename -s .vim {} + | sort -u`

Comment: Nice, way more succinct. Any better solution for finding the VIMRUNTIME value from terminal as well?

Comment: `vim -Nesc '!echo $VIMRUNTIME' -c qa`, I think.

Comment: Yikes. That second command is frightening. Sorry. I'm not being not nice. ;) For fun, here's a Bash alternative to muru's suggestion that uses just one external command (assuming `printf` is a builtin): `f=({ftplugin,syntax}/*.vim) && f=(${f[@]##*/}) && printf "%s\n" "${f[@]%%.*}" | sort -u` . See "Parameter Expansion" in Bash man page for explanation of the hieroglyphics.

Comment: This will give you psuedo filetype plugins like `bash`, which is 'not a real filetype plugin ... and gets the effect of filetype "sh"'

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax. Use :echo $VIMRUNTIME to know its value. In my computer, $VIMRUNTIME/syntax was /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax. It has all the syntax files.

If you have a vim with gui, you can also use Syntax menu to get all the filetypes supported.