# List known abbreviations for filetypes

Tags: filetype, modeline

[This VI StackExchange message thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5780/2808) provides useful tips for generating a list of known filetypes.  However, I often see Vim modelines use abbreviations like `js` for `javascript`.  These abbreviated forms (e.g., `js`) are not shown when I issue a command such as

```
:setfiletype <Ctrl-d>
```

to list the known filetypes.

So how do I obtain a list of known/supported abbreviations for filetypes?

Comment: I don't have the impression that these abbreviations are accepted by `:setfiletype` command. With my configuration `:setfiletype` set the filetype literally. Is it different for you? What is the result of `:setfiletype js` and then `:set ft?`?

Comment: No, there is no such thing as "abbreviations for filetypes".

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comments.  I sometimes come across webpages and source code with VIM modelines that use abbreviations like 'txt' (which is either a typo, or is intended to be an abbreviation for 'text'), and I got to wondering if maybe the file type strings can be abbreviated a la VIM commands--e.g., set filetype=cpp, or, set ft=cpp

Comment: 1. `txt` can be two things: a typo or an actual user-defined filetype. 2. `cpp` *is* the filetype.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? Otherwise maybe could you accept an answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons? It allows the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 3):

file type abbreviations are not accepted by the `:setfiletype` command.

The `:setfiletype` set the filetype literally.

e.g.:

```
:setfiletype js
```

Set the filetype to `js` (`:set ft?` returns `js`) which is not equivalent to `javascript`

Comment: Indeed `javascript` and `js` are two different filetypes, the former being the only valid one in Vim out of the box.